# How to insert a block of code in terraform using templatefile

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I am new to terraform and trying to figure out a way to insert a dynamic block of code in a terraform file.

I was trying the [templatefile Function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile) sample of expected output pseudo code:

```
application_stack { 
  dotnet_version = "6.0"
  use_dotnet_isolated_runtime = true
}
```

I have a demo file e.g. demo.tfpl

```
%{ for config_key, config_value in config }
  ${config_key} = ${config_value}
%{ endfor ~}
```

In my main.tf file:

```
application_stack {
templatefile(
              "${path.module}/demo.tftpl",
              {
                config = {
                  "dotnet_version" = "6.0"
                  "use_dotnet_isolated_runtime" = "true"
                }
              }
            )
}
```

As it is documented I get the error: `An argument or block definition is required here`.

Unfortunately in my case I can not use a key e.g. (pseudo code):

```
sample_key = yamlencode({
  [for config_key, config_value in config : "${config_key} = ${config_value}"],
})
```

I can not use a key e.g. `sample_key`. I want to insert the code in a block directly.

Is there any way to do that?

I thought of using even [replace Function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/replace) but the text is not fixed either in the block or the text that I want to insert.

My idea is to be able to insert any kind of block code not only a key value combination.

For example use the template and insert another block e.g. (pseudo code):

```
application_stack {
  docker {
    key1 = "value1"
    key2 = "value2"
    key3 = "value3"
    key4 = "value4"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do this in terraform?

Comment: You can't. Such thing is not supported in TF.

Comment: That is what I am afraid of. Thank you for your time @Marcin

Comment: You're expected to use modules for TF code reuse, not templates. I suspect this is an xy problem where the answer is [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) but that's a guess based on the limited info here.

Comment: Hello @jordanm, you are absolutely right. Initially I thought that I could use templates to create tf files with replsced content on the fly like Jinja2 in Ansible. I miss understood the concept of templates in terraform. Regarding dynamic blocks. It was also my first attempt to my problem but on this specific case it does not work. My goal was to use [linux_function_app](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_function_app) and replace dynamically the key/values. On functions the dynamic block does not work unfortunately.